# PHP Array Split

Tags: php, arrays

I am not really sure that this issue is about splinting an array. I am running into a wall because i cant seem to find the best way to do this.

I have a mutlydimetional array that looks like this.

```
Array ( [0] => ) 
[20] => Array ( [0] => Time[s] [1] => B2 [2] => F3 [3] => C6 [4] => F7 ) 
[21] => Array ( [0] => 0.0 [1] => 57.68 [2] => 58.83 [3] => 58.95 [4] => 59.11 ) 
[22] => Array ( [0] => 0.5 [1] => 58.12 [2] => 59.21 [3] => 59.24 [4] => 59.43 )
```

This array can go on for thousands of arrays. It is a temperature reading for multiple point every few second.

What I am trying to do is split it in multiple pages or multiple tables but iterating in the same code so that i can use the same background or style table.

Table 1 Results 1 - 10

```
1
2
3
4
5
..
```

Table 2 Results 11 - 21

```
11
12
13
14
15
......
```

And so on.

So fart I have this. But it only seems to give me the entire list. No matter what i tried I cant seems to figure out how to split it. Any help will be appreciate it.

```
 echo '<table border="1">';
 echo '<tbody>';
    for ($row = 20; $row <  $rows; $row++) {

      echo '<tr>';

    for ($col = 0; $col <  15; $col++) {
   echo "<td>".$csvarray[$row][$col]."</td>";

     }

    echo '</tr>';

     } 

    echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Off-topic tip: goto Google translator a take a look what 'fart' really means :D

Comment: You're only breaking a table into rows yes? So why not chuck the whole lot into a single loop and use modulo to put the `</tr><tr>` in every X records?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need another loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_rows; $i++) {
   echo "<p>Table " . ($i + 1) . "</p><table>";
   for ($j = ($i+1)* 20; ...) {
      echo "<tr>";
      for ($k = 0; $k < 15; $k++) {
             echo "<td> .... </td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
}
```

The `$i` loop creates your `Table X` headings. `$j` loop handles building the rows, `$k` loop handles building the columns.

Comment: Thank you Marc this worked great, not sure how i over looked this. I was looking at all kind of functions but this was really simple and exactly to the point.

Comment: Hi Marc i replaced all the variables with the ones i use but i keep getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';'  on this like for ($j = ($i+1)* 20; ...) {  . from my understanding the ... will be my variable $csvarray[$row] am i correct. Sorry i am actually pretty new a php.

Comment: it'd be `($i+1)*20+$rows_you_want_in_your_tables`, basically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_slice()` function. It's like a substr function for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so In the end i used a combination of all the answers here is the result in case somebody is looking for the same question.

```
$csvarray = array_chunk($csvarray, 20);

$tables = count($csvarray);

for ($table = 1; $table <  $tables; $table++) {
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tbody>';

echo $table + 1;

$rows = count($csvarray[$table]);
for ($row = 0; $row <  $rows; $row++) {

$vals = count($csvarray[$table][$row]);
echo '<tr>';

for ($val = 0; $val <  $vals; $val++) {
echo "<td>".$csvarray[$table][$row][$val]."</td>";

}

echo '</tr>';

}
```